# Aligning columns in a console output table correctly and starting to count from zero

Tags: java, netbeans, console, console-application

So I've got this Java code in which I'm trying to output all 128 possible ASCII codes, their hexadecimal value, and their decimal value. Here's the code I have now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            Scanner Number = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many groups: ");
            int usernumber = Number.nextInt();

            int counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
                   String output = "";
                    if (j == 7 | j == 8 | j == 9 | j == 10 | j == 13){
                      output += " ";
                    } else {
                       output += (char) j;
                    }
                    output += " " + j + " " + Integer.toHexString(j);

                    if (Integer.toHexString(j).length() < 2){
                        output += "     ";
                    } else {
                        output += "\t";
                    }

                    if (counter == usernumber) {
                        output += "\n";
                        counter = 0;
                    }

                    System.out.print(output);
                    counter++;
                }
                System.out.println("\n ");
            }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve **this**:

[image: Desired Output]

However, my console output isn't formatting correctly and my table is horribly misconstrued as you can see **[here]**:

[image: Current Output]

Any help or ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? In my code, I tried to make up for space left null due to some numbers being assigned to sounds or other characters that can't be correctly outputted in the console and whatnot.

Comment: Formatting with tab can provide unwanted results. From what I can tell, the example above would most likely be used with constant spacing. Each character only takes up one space, not like you have to account for String lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding different types of characters, as in:

```
if (Integer.toHexString(j).length() < 2){
    output += "     ";
} else {
    output += "\t";
}
```

you should try setting the proper number of characters on which value should be displayed, you can do it using String.format, try altering the following syntax.

```
String.format("%-2s - %-2d", stringValue, intValue);
```

You can change your for into the following code, which will do the job

```
for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
        counter++;
        char firstChar = (char) j;
        if (j == 7 || j == 8 || j == 9 || j == 10 || j == 13) {
            firstChar = ' ';
        }
        String output = String.format("%-3s %-3d %-4s", firstChar, j, Integer.toHexString(j));

        if (counter == usernumber) {
            System.out.println(output);
            counter = 0;
        }else{
            System.out.print(output);
        }
    }
```

Additionally, there was a problem with counter set in wrong place - you can try to change it to modulo.